# How to fix the position of a gradient in Illustrator, so that it doesn't move when I edit the object it's applied to?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, path

How do I make Illustrator not change the gradient's position and size when I change the path's shape?

[image] [image]

Answer (score 2):

Essentially you don't. Gradient fills are based on the boundaries of the shape they are applied to. If you alter the boundaries, then the gradient position and length will change. It is simply how gradient fills work.

It's a very simple matter to grab the **Gradient Tool** and **move the annotator** to where you want it.

Comment: Scott, thank you for the answer! Is it possible to rightly position the gradient using the Gradient Tool then? In other words, can I set certain X and Y of gradient ends?

Comment: No gradient in Illustrator allows you to set the X and Y specifically. But, using the Gradient Tool you can't manually move the start and end points as well as the size and shape of radial gradients. I'd provide screenshots, but you can't easily take screenshots of the Annotator.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by using a second path and a clipping mask:

1. Original shape

   [image]
2. Original shape with the second shape

   [image]
3. Right click to the document with both shapes selected

   [image]
4. The result:

   [image]

Answer (score 2):

Basically I draw a line parallel to the slider and after changing the shape I make the new slider follow that line. Of course you can also use a piece of tape on your screen. To make it myself easier use the following combinations: line ("\"), gradient tool (G) and select object below (cmd+alt+[)

Another way is to use the Info window to show the slider's coordinates. It also shows the slider's height, width, angle and length. Makes me wonder if someone could make use of this to create a guide line

Answer (score 0):

If you have an object with a gradient and want to change the shape without affecting the gradient, use the Pathfinder "divide", and subtract it with another shape. When it's divided you can delete the parts that you don't need and you'll leave the gradient intact. Try this and let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question has been asked more than 8 years ago I post my answer to it for any later references to this page (this answer was tested on *Adobe Illustrator CC 2018*):

1. Let's suppose you have objects like this:
   [image]
2. move and select both objects in a way that the black rectangle is over the one with gradient color (the other unselected one is for final comparison):
   [image]
3. hit the `Properties > Pathfinders > Trim` from the right panel
   [image]
4. delete all unwanted anchor points with Direct Selection Tool (A).
   [image]
   [image]